IIS Asking Specific User for Credentials Repeatedly
The business I work for has had an intranet site for a while now with very little issue. Recently we had a new person start in our shipping department and every time he tries to log into the intranet, he gets prompted to enter his credentials. After entering his credentials, the site then prompts for his credentials again, with no message of it being invalid or anything like that. If he closes the authentication window, it says unauthorized.
At this point we've tried to use a different user's credentials and that works fine, and if another user logs into the same computer, they're not prompted for credentials, and they are let into the intranet normally. This is the only user this issue happens with and having them try different computers doesn't make a difference either. I have also tried to disable look back via reg edit, remove negotiate as an option from the authentication settings in IIS but the issue still persists. It's a very odd issue as this is the only user this happens to, and we have replicated his access exactly as other users in the shipping department with no luck. Any help is appreciated.

It's actually not a rare case. Your domain administrators can usually go deeper into the account (and its attributes like group membership) to learn what's the offending factor that causes Windows/IIS to fail. Not something you can resolve from your IIS configuration or web app code.

Check the Windows Application & System EventLog's on the end users PC, the domain controller and IIS server around the time of some of your failed login attempts. If your using integrated auth you should see something. If you create another user does that work as expected or gets the same issue?

For this problem happening to a specific user of an internal site, I think you can check if this user has read permissions set to the directory on the server.

Right click on your site in IIS under the Sites folder
Click Edit Permissions...
Select the Security tab
Under the Group or usernames section click the Edit... button
In the Permissions pop up, under the Group or user names click Add...
Enter Specific User in the object names to select text area and click OK to apply the change
Click OK to close the Permissions pop up
Click OK to close the Properties pop up and apply your new settings

